# No such host is known in Test and Production

Tags: iis, .net-core

In my .Net Core controller I have a "PublishDraft" action.  This works as expected in localhost during development.  Once this is deployed to the Test or Production servers, this action returns the "No such host is known" error.

This is one of many actions on this controller, and they all work in Test and Production except for this one single PublishDraft() action.  So this tells me it cannot be a DNS issue since all the other actions work.

```cs
        [HttpPost("PublishDraft")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PublishDraft([FromBody] PublishDraftRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var existing = _unitOfWork.Drafts.GetAll(d => d.Id == request.DraftId, null, "DraftTags").FirstOrDefault();

                if (existing == null)
                {
                    return NotFound("Draft does not exist");
                }

                var created = await _unitOfWork.Drafts.PublishDraft(existing, User.Claims.GetUserId());

                if (created.TreeNodeTypeId == (int)TreeNodeTypes.Private && created.ParentId != null)
                {
                    await _unitOfWork.TreeNodeUser.UpdateUserPermissionsAsync(created.Id, created.ParentId, User.Claims.GetUserId());
                }

                return Created("TreeNode", created);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, User);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Whether I test this using the web client (Angular) or PostMan in Test or Production, I get the same error on this single action.

The servers are IIS 10.

Any ideas why this is happening?

UPDATE:

To answer questions from the commenters about what the exception call stack shows, there is no exception!  The controller action is never hit, so no exception is logged.

UPDATE 2 - Added screenshots of error

Dev Tools Header screenshot
(I removed the domain name in this screenshot)

[image: Dev Tools Header screenshot]

Dev Tools Response screenshot
[image: Dev Tools Response screenshot]

I found an interesting anomaly that changes the way I look at this issue, I'm only getting the "unknown host" error when the DraftId exists.  But when I pass in a bogus DraftId, then I get the error message "Draft does not exist", which tells me that the controller action is actually being hit after all.

I still don't know why the "unknown host" error occurs in Test or Production and it works locally in development, but I'm adding some trace logging to see if I can find out where the issue is occurring.

**Solved** - Sept. 9, 2021

It's simply a cause of not being consistent on my part.  It all came down to a trailing slash on an endpoint.

(Sprinkling trace logs throughout my code helped me track down the cause.)

My service needs to use the `HttpClient` to call an external api from inside the `PublishDraft()` method of the controller action.

My localhost appSettings has a config for the base endpoint like this:

```js
  "EndPointsConfig": {
    "FileStore": "https://localhost:44314/"
  }
```

The trailing slash is correct.

My `Testing` and `Production` appSettings properties were:

```js
  "EndPointsConfig": {
    "FileStore": "https://filestore.domain.com"
  }
```

The missing trailing slash caused the "No such host is known" error, since it had to concat the path to a method and with no slash `/` it was clearly incorrect.

Like this: `https://filestore.domain.com/deleterange`

Once the slash was added, it all worked!

Hopefully others find this useful in solving similar issues.

Comment: What specific line throws the error? What's the full error message and stack trace, and details about any inner exceptions? Did you actually take the time to validate that the URL is matching what it should be in this point in the code, or did you assume it's matching your expectation without verifying it?

Comment: The actual call stack of an exception is as important as the exception error message. So without enough information, no one else can easily help.

Comment: @mason - that's just it, the controller action is never hit, so there is no exception.  If I had an exception, I would post it here.  I've also added a global exception handler to catch any and all unhandled exceptions, and still no errors are logged.

Comment: @mason - as I mentioned, this code works, locally, without any errors.  It Posts the payload and returns the correct response with data. But when deployed to the Test or Production servers, this single controller action is never hit.  Yes I can verify that the URL matches the intended endpoint.

Comment: You say "this action returns....the error" - so now you're saying this action actually isn't even getting hit? How did you set up your global exception handler? And where are you seeing the "No such host is known" message? In the browser? What networking components exist between your client and web server that might potentially generate an error page?

Comment: @mason - the global exception handler is a class that is added to the request pipeline. `app.UseMiddleware(typeof(GlobalExceptionHandler));`  To be clear, when I said that the action returns the error, I meant that when that endpoint is hit, this is the error that is returned.  You can see that the action has a Try/Catch block, but for some reason it is not being hit, otherwise I would see error logs, and unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: Okay - so what other networking devices are between your client and your web server that might generate the error message?

Comment: @mason - I see the error response in the browser dev tools if I'm testing the Angular client, or in PostMan if I'm hitting the endpoint directly.  There are no network components between the client and web server.

Comment: Is it possible some layer earlier in your middleware (before you've registered the global exception handler) is throwing the error? And also, if you look at the [mcve] page, I think you'll want to pick one of the 2 approaches mentioned there (Restart From Scratch or Divide And Conquer) to try to isolate where the error is coming from.

Comment: @mason - I'll take a look at that example, though I still don't know why all other actions work and this one doesn't.

Comment: @KingWilder Pls show pic about `No such host is known` msg for us.